# Add multiple value in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application, in React i have next situation:
I have input where  i add different values when i click on `save`. The value from input is converted from string to array.
So, first time i added a text, i clicked save, and i have 1 value in array.
Second time, i add another text, i click, on save and the first value is changed by second.
I store value in this state:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState([here comes my value]);
```

I  want to concat the value one after one and i did:

```js
useEffect(()=> {
    setAllValues([...value, value])
  }, [value])
```

..but this does't work. How to store all values in one array?

Comment: It doesn't work because you use `setAllValues` where your function name is `setValue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [functional form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) of `setState`:

```
 setAllValues(prevValue => [...prevValue, newValue])
```

Answer (score 1):

To perform that operation you would need two states

```js
// one state for array
const [valueArray, setValueArray] = useState([here comes my value]);

// and another state for string
const [value, setValue] = useState('');


// then onSave function
const onSave = () => {
  setValueArray([  ...valueArray, value ]);
  setValue('');
}
```